# is it possible to write entire python output to a text or csv file?

Tags: python, csv, save, output

i'm new to python and working on traceroute so I was wondering if it's possible to write entire python traceroute result output to txt and Csv file? any idea how can i achieve that because i can't find any proper one which shows how to do it.

thanks

Comment: it needs to be done from within the python script!

Answer (score 2):

```
import subprocess

with open("hostlist.txt", "r") as hostlist, open("results.txt", "a") as output:
    for host in hostlist:
        host = host.strip()

        print "Tracing", host

        trace = subprocess.Popen(["tracert", "-w", "100", host], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

        while True:
            hop = trace.stdout.readline()

            if not hop: break

            print '-->', hop.strip()
            output.write(hop)

        # When you pipe stdout, the doc recommends that you use .communicate()
        # instead of wait()
        # see: http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait
        trace.communicate()
```

I am reading host details from hostlist and writing o/p in a file